There are a lot of foreign students living in this building [Bare or extented existential?]
H&P's CGEL says this under 6.2 The existential construction:

6.2.1 Survey of structures (p. 1393)
The distinction between bare and extended existentials   We draw a distinction between bare and extended existentials [...]
(a) Bare existentials [...]
(b) Locative and temporal extensions [...]
(c) Predicative extensions [...]
(d) Infinitival extensions [...]
(e) Participial extensions (p. 1394-5) 
Existential clauses in which be is followed by a noun that is in
turn followed by a participial clause may be construed syntactically
in two ways. Firstly, the subordinate clause may be a modifier of the
noun and hence part of the displaced subject NP: (1)
There were [specimens m̲e̲a̲s̲u̲r̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲o̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲t̲w̲e̲l̲v̲e̲ ̲i̲n̲c̲h̲e̲s̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲l̲e̲n̲g̲t̲h̲]. (2)
There were [some letters w̲r̲i̲t̲t̲e̲n̲ ̲b̲y̲ ̲h̲e̲r̲ ̲g̲r̲a̲n̲d̲m̲o̲t̲h̲e̲r̲] in the safe.
Example (1) is a bare existential, while (2) has a locative extension
in the safe. Secondly, the subordinate clause
may be an extension, not part of the displaced
subject NP: (3) There were [some boys] p̲l̲a̲y̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲c̲r̲i̲c̲k̲e̲t̲.   (4) There
were [several people] k̲i̲l̲l̲e̲d̲. The non-existential counterparts of
these are Some boys were playing cricket and Several people were
killed, whereas the counterpart of (2) is Some letters written by
her grandmother were in the safe. Example (1), being a bare
existential, has no non-existential counterpart, but we understand it
as asserting the existence of specimens that measured over twelve
inches in length.

According to CGEL, is (5) a bare or extended existential?(5) There are a lot of foreign students l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲.
If l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ is part of the displaced subject NP and is parsed as There are [a lot of foreign students l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲], (5) is a bare existential.
If l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ is not part of the displaced subject NP and is parsed as There are [a lot of foreign students] l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲, (5) is an extended existential.
EDIT
I was reading 'Functional English Grammar', which says:

Clauses such as (55) There are a lot of foreign students living in this building. can be compared to: (55) a. A lot of foreign students live in this building. The existential structure in number 55 serves in a sense to push the participants a lot of foreign students away from the Theme, which as we have seen is typically associated with given information, and into a position more appropriate for new information. The second process must then be realized by an embedded clause, typically a Ving clause as in number 55.

The book seems to think that Sentence 55 means Sentence 55a, not "A lot of foreign students are living in this building". So to the book at least, the salient reading of 55 is 55a (without the progressive aspect). Now to CGEL, the salient reading of 3 (There were some boys playing cricket) is "Some boys were playing cricket" (with the progressive aspect).
And I tend to agree with both the book's reading of 55 and CGEL's reading of 3. So I need to investigate what determines whether the gerund-participial of an existential construction carries the progressive aspect in the salient reading.

As you said, it depends on how you parse it. If you parse it as "There are [a lot of foreign students living in this building]" it is a bare existential, and if you parse it as "There are [a lot of foreign students] [living in this building]" then it is an extended existential. Rules of pure syntax, unconnected to semantics, would allow either of these parses.
So we need to take semantics, or interpretation of what we guess is the intended meaning of the sentence, into account. It seems to me that the sentence has essentially the same meaning as the following non-existential counterpart: "A lot of foreign students are living in this building."
Quoth CGEL: "a bare existential, has no non-existential counterpart."
Therefore, sentence 5) is not a bare existential.
Conclusion: It is an extended existential.
If you object that sentence 5) could be understood instead as asserting the existence of a lot of foreign students that are living in this building, I would reply that you could make the same objection to CGEL's example (3) (saying that it could be understood to assert the existence of some boys that were playing cricket). My take is that such readings, while perhaps syntactically possible, aren't very natural.
As for the question about aspect, I don't think there is actually a  precise, one-to-one correspondence between "A lot of foreign students live in this building" and "There are a lot of foreign students living] in this building." So my take is that Functional English Grammar is not presenting a precise equivalence (note that it uses the wording "can be compared to" rather than something like "can be transformed into"). Obviously, they are sentences with similar meanings that share a lot of the same words. But you can say the same thing about the pair of sentences "A lot of foreign students live in this building" and "A lot of foreign students are living in this building." It's basically a coincidence that the verb live happens to have similar meanings in some cases when used in the simple aspect vs. the progressive aspect.
If we take another verb, such as love, that doesn't traditionally  show as much wiggle room in its aspect as live does, we can note that "A lot of students love basketball" is a natural-sounding sentence but "There are a lot of students loving basketball" is not a natural-sounding sentence. This suggests that there is no general rule establishing a correspondence between the progressive aspect in existential constructions and the simple aspect in non-existential constructions.

Does (5) mean "A lot of foreign students are living in this building" or "A lot of foreign students live in this building"? Which is the correct non-existential counterpart?

Can (3), There were [some boys] p̲l̲a̲y̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲c̲r̲i̲c̲k̲e̲t̲, also mean both Some boys were playing cricket and Some boys played cricket? I think it means the former but not the latter. This means we can use the extended existential with a gerund-participial extension only when we intend to express the progressive aspect. Therefore, if (5) is intended to convey the progressive aspect I'm sure it's an extended existential. But if it's intended not to convey the progressive aspect, how can it be considered an extended existential?

So are you suggesting that (5)'s l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ cannot be parsed as There are [a lot of foreign students l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲], where l̲i̲v̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲b̲u̲i̲l̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ can be expanded to a relative clause who live in this building?

But by the same logic, There were specimens measuring over twelve inches in length can be converted to Specimens were measuring over twelve inches in length and CGEL says it can't be converted to a non-existential.

@StuartF: This isn't about any kind of mechanical conversion.  "A lot of foreign students are living in this building" makes sense and means essentially the same thing as "There are a lot of foreign students living in this building" whereas "Specimens were measuring over twelve inches in length" sounds unnatural/wrong.

Please see my EDIT. I hope you post an answer. Thanks.

@StuartF Shouldn’t the more sensible conversion be Some specimens measured over twelve inches in length using a simple past tense? After all, measure is here used more as a stative verb than a dynamic one and therefore in this context resists mechanical conversions to ‘progressives’ using some inflection of be followed by an ‑ɪɴɢ form. This is not “an inchworm measuring the marigolds” scenario where you have a transitive verb plus its direct object. It’s really just a stative assertion about the specimens’ length; they are not themselves getting actively measured here.

Thanks for the edit. The fact that There are a lot of students loving basketball is not natural, which I agree with, suggests to me that the gerund-participial phrase loving basketball cannot be understood to mean "who love basketball". If it could, There are a lot of students loving basketball should be as natural as There are a lot of students who love basketball, which I find natural enough. And I don't think this is limited to an existential. I know a lot of students loving basketball sounds unnatural whereas I know a lot of students living in this building is okay. Go figure.

The difference in acceptability between a lot of students loving basketball and a lot of students living in this building, however, cannot simply be attributed to the difference in acceptability between a lot of students (who) are loving basketball and a lot of students (who) are living in this building. This is because, in CGEL's example (1), specimens measuring over twelve inches in length is a well-formed NP although specimens (which) are measuring over twelve inches in length is unacceptable with or without which.

I can't get your parse at all there. It's either "There are [a lot of foreign students][living in the building]" or it's "There are [a lot of foreign students living in this building]" where the long NP has the structure [a lot of [foreign students living in this building]].

@Araucaria-Him: Thanks—I mistyped the brackets!

In the existential 'There + be + NP + XP', do you think it's safe to say that it's always an extended existential unless 'NP + be + XP' doesn't work, in which case it's a bare existential?
